# Filter through an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one array with a list of all cars, as follows :

```
const allCars = [
       {id: 1, listID: 1, name: "Car 1", chassis: "000000000"},
       {id: 2, listID: 2, name: "Car 2", chassis: "111111111"},
       {id: 3, listID: 1, name: "Car 3", chassis: "222222222"},
       {id: 4, listID: 1, name: "Car 4", chassis: "333333333"}
    ];
```

and I have some of those cars in the shopping cart, as follows :

```
const carsInCart = [
           {carID: 1, listID: 1, offer: 488},
           {carID: 2, listID: 2, offer: 786},
        ]
```

Is there any way to filter throught allCars and return only those which are in carsInCart, and return only chassis from allCars and offer from carsInCart?

Thus, what I want is something like this :

```
const result = [
   {chassis: 000000000, offer: 488},
   {chassis: 111111111, offer: 786}
]
```

Comment: Note: you appear to be using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) where [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) would be more appropriate. Using them as you have implies that you might have some confusion as to where to use each of these statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
const result = carsInCart.map(function (car) {
  const aCar = allCars.find(function (c) {
    return c.id === car.ID;
  });
  return { chassis: aCar.chassis, offer: car.offer };
});
```

Or with functions shorthands:

```
const result = carsInCart.map(car => {
  chassis: allCars.find(c => c.id === car.ID).chassis,
  offer:   car.offer
});
```

Comment: One word : Brilliant! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const result = carsInCart.map(carInCart => ({
  offer: carIncart.offer,
  chassis: allCars.find(car => car.id === carInCart.carID).chassis
}));
```

or even shorter with destructing assignment.

```
const result = carsInCart.map(({carID,offer}) => ({
  offer,
  chassis: allCars.find(({id}) => id === carID).chassis
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for loops:

```
const allCars = [
   {id: 1, listID: 1, name: "Car 1", chassis: "000000000"},
   {id: 2, listID: 2, name: "Car 2", chassis: "111111111"},
   {id: 3, listID: 1, name: "Car 3", chassis: "222222222"},
   {id: 4, listID: 1, name: "Car 4", chassis: "333333333"}
];

const carsInCart = [
   {carID: 1, listID: 1, offer: 488},
   {carID: 2, listID: 2, offer: 786},
]

var result = []; //result goes here

//for each car
for(var i = 0; i < allCars.length; i++) {

    var car = allCars[i]; //current car

    //for each item in cart
    for(var k = 0; k < carsInCart.length; k++) {

        var cartItem = carsInCart[k]; //current cart item

        //if the current cart ID matches the current cart item ID
        if(car.id == cartItem.carID) {

            //its a match, add to result
            result.push({ chassis: car.chassis, offer: cartItem.offer });

        }

    }

}
```

Edit: 
[.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility) aren't supported by all browsers yet so they can't be used in web development.

Answer (score 0):

```
const allCars = [
   {id: 1, listID: 1, name: "Car 1", chassis: "000000000"},
   {id: 2, listID: 2, name: "Car 2", chassis: "111111111"},
   {id: 3, listID: 1, name: "Car 3", chassis: "222222222"},
   {id: 4, listID: 1, name: "Car 4", chassis: "333333333"}
];

const carsInCart = [
  {carID: 1, listID: 1, offer: 488},
  {carID: 2, listID: 2, offer: 786},
]

var carsFilter = [];

carsInCart.forEach(function(car) {
  var matchingCar = jQuery.grep(array, function(item) {
    return item.id == car.carID;
  })[0];

  carsFilter.push({ 
    chassis: matchingCar.chassis, 
    offer: car.offer 
  });
});

// The result is the object `carsFilter`, if you didn't work that out!
console.log(carsFilter);
```

Comment: no idea why the downvote.  Note the result was to be `result`, not `carsFilter`, even if `carsFilter` is more descriptive.

Comment: OP didn't mention jQuery. I don't think you should use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not want to use jquery.